# SQL Server - identify combinations of values and assign combination identifier

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, combinations

I am trying to assign what amounts to a 'combinationid' to rows of my table, based on the values in the two columns below. Each product has a number of customers linked to it. For every combination of customers, I need to create a combination ID.

For example, the combination of customers for product 'a' is the same combination of customers for product 'c' (they both have customers 1, 2 and 3), so products a and c should have the same combination identifier ('customergroup'). However, products should not share the same customergroup if they only share some of the same customers - e.g. product b only has customers 1 and 2 (not 3), so should have a different customergroup to products 'a' and 'c'.

Input:

```
| productid | customerid |
|-----------|------------|
| a         | 1          |
| a         | 2          |
| a         | 3          |
| b         | 1          |
| b         | 2          |
| c         | 3          |
| c         | 2          |
| c         | 1          |
| d         | 1          |
| d         | 3          |
| e         | 1          |
| e         | 2          |
| f         | 1          |
| g         | 2          |
| h         | 3          |
```

Desired output:

```
| productid | customerid | customergroup |
|-----------|------------|---------------|
| a         | 1          | 1             |
| a         | 2          | 1             |
| a         | 3          | 1             |
| b         | 1          | 2             |
| b         | 2          | 2             |
| c         | 3          | 1             |
| c         | 2          | 1             |
| c         | 1          | 1             |
| d         | 1          | 3             |
| d         | 3          | 3             |
| e         | 1          | 2             |
| e         | 2          | 2             |
| f         | 1          | 4             |
| g         | 2          | 5             |
| h         | 3          | 6             |
```

or just

```
| productid | customergroupid |
|-----------|-----------------|
| a         | 1               |
| b         | 2               |
| c         | 1               |
| d         | 3               |
| e         | 2               |
| f         | 4               |
| g         | 5               |
| h         | 6               |
```

Edit: first version of this did include a description of my attempts. I currently have nested queries that basically give me a column for customer 1, 2, 3 etc and then uses dense rank to get the grouping. The problem is that is not dynamic for different numbers of customers and I did not know where to start for getting a dynamic result as above. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I can think of one way you could achieve this, however, what have you tried so far? Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, so please do show us your attempts first. Thanks.

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you haven't shown your efforts, or confirmed the version you're using, I've assumed you have the latest ("and greatest") version of SQL Server, which means you have access to `STRING_AGG`.

This doesn't give the groupings in the same order, but I'm going to also also that doesn't matter, and the grouping is just arbitrary. This gives you the following:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('a',1),
            ('a',2),
            ('a',3),
            ('b',1),
            ('b',2),
            ('c',3),
            ('c',2),
            ('c',1),
            ('d',1),
            ('d',3),
            ('e',1),
            ('e',2),
            ('f',1),
            ('g',2),
            ('h',3)) V(productid,customerid)),
Groups AS(
    SELECT productid,
           STRING_AGG(customerid,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY customerid) AS CustomerIDs
    FROM VTE
    GROUP BY productid),
Rankings AS(
    SELECT productid,
           CustomerIDs,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerIDs ASC) AS Grouping
    FROM Groups)
SELECT V.productid,
       V.customerid,
       R.Grouping AS customergroupid
FROM VTE V
     JOIN Rankings R ON V.productid = R.productid
ORDER BY V.productid,
         V.customerid;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4008c08099628067a89586bddf0d9dc5).

If you aren't using SQL Server 2017, I suggest looking up the `FOR XML PATH` method for string aggregation.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I mistakenly overwrote my efforts description when posting tables yesterday. I am using 2008 so I will attempt with your guidance above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using Larnu's answer this is how I got the result for 2008:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('a','1'),
            ('a','2'),
            ('a','3'),
            ('b','1'),
            ('b','2'),
            ('c','3'),
            ('c','2'),
            ('c','1'),
            ('d','1'),
            ('d','3'),
            ('e','1'),
            ('e','2'),
            ('f','1'),
            ('g','2'),
            ('h','3')) V(productid,customerid)),
Groups AS(
    SELECT productid, CustomerIDs = STUFF((SELECT N', ' + customerid 
    FROM VTE AS p2
    WHERE p2.productid = p.productid 
    ORDER BY customerid
    FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'')
    FROM VTE AS p
    GROUP BY productid),
Rankings AS(
    SELECT productid,
           CustomerIDs,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerIDs ASC) AS Grouping
    FROM Groups)
SELECT V.productid,
       V.customerid,
       R.Grouping AS customergroupid
FROM VTE V
     JOIN Rankings R ON V.productid = R.productid
ORDER BY V.productid,
         V.customerid;
```

Thanks again for your assistance.